# Expectation with indicator function

Tags: expected-value, indicator-function

I have the following expectation

$$E[x_{t+1} \mathbf{1}_{\{x_{t+1}> z_t\}}]$$

where $x_{t+1}$ is a normally distributed random variable $x_{t+1}\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, and $\mathbf{1}$ stands for the indicator function.
$z_t$ is a function of variables, as in $z_t = f(y_t,p_t)$, which I eventually need to solve for.

I need an analytical representation of this expectation.

Please let me know if this is unclear or need to add additional info. I am clearly new here.

Comment: Welcome to CV. As it stands, your question is quite sketchy and risks being deleted. Please elaborate on factors related to your question: is there an analytic context for this query? Is there any actual data associated with it? Would you be able to share a sample of it? What is the unit of observation? What is the unit of time? And so on.

Comment: there is no data associated to it. x is just a random variable normally distributed. I just want to know what it the analytical expression of this. And time is discrete. I do not understand why of the downgrade.

Comment: It's just a way to alert the more senior guys on CV that there may be an issue with your question that needs their attention. Their collective opinions will make the decision regarding your question. One way to hedge your risk of deletion is to provide more information and context, as noted above.

Comment: Yes, please explain better. Do not understand what the $ 1_{\{x_{t+1}> z_t\}}$ means without guessing. Also, have to guess what a shock is.

Comment: What are $f$, $y_t$ and $p_t$? Are they important or is the question just how to compute $E(x_{t+1}\,I_{\{x_{t+1}>c\}})$?

Comment: I is the indicator function. I just want to know how to compute the expectation. The function f is important because I have the values I need to solve for inside that piece. So I am looking for an analytical expression for this expectation that I can use in later stages of my calculations. Does this help? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original random variable $X_{t+1}$ is normally distributed. Call its distribution $P_{X_{t+1}}$

Define a function

$$g(v) = v \cdot 1_{\{v > z_t\}}$$

where $1_{\{\cdot\}}$ is the indicator function. This can also be written as:

$$g(v) = \left \{
    \begin{array}{cl}
        v & v > z_t \\
        0 & \text{Otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right .$$

Another way to phrase your question is: what is the expected value of $g(X_{t+1})$? We can write this as:

$$E[g(X_t)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(v) P_{X_{t+1}}(v) dv$$

We know that $g(v) = 0$ for $v \le z_t$, and $g(v) = v$ for $v > z_t$. So, we can split the integral across two intervals:

$$E[g(X_t)] = \int_{-\infty}^{z_t} 0 \cdot P_{X_{t+1}}(v) dv
+ \int_{z_t}^{\infty} v \cdot P_{X_{t+1}}(v) dv$$

The first term is clearly zero, so we're left with:

$$E[g(X_t)] = \int_{z_t}^{\infty} v \cdot P_{X_{t+1}}(v) dv$$

$X_{t+1}$ is normally distributed, so we can substitute $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ in for $P_{X_{t+1}}$

$$E[g(X_t)] = \int_{z_t}^{\infty} \frac{v}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left [ {-\frac{(v-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}} \right ] dv$$

Evaluating the integral gives the final answer:

$$
E[g(X_t)] = 
\frac{\mu}{2} \left [
    1 - \text{erf} \left (
        \frac{z_t - \mu}{\sigma \sqrt{2}}
    \right )
\right ]
+ {
    \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}
    \exp \left [
        -\frac{(z_t - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}
    \right ]
}
$$

where $\text{erf}(\cdot)$ is the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

You can check that this is correct by simulation. Draw many samples from $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, set values less than $z_t$ to zero, then take the sample mean.

**Edit** (as suggested by user12):

In the case where $X_{t+1}$ has mean zero, plug $\mu = 0$ into the last equation above, to obtain:

$$
E[g(X_t)] = 
    \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}
    \exp \left [
        -\frac{z_t^2}{2 \sigma^2}
    \right ]
$$

Comment: Thank you user20160. I have looked at your answer and it is brilliantly explained. I have taken a further step, please would you be able to tell me if I am correct? The mean $$\mu$$ is 0, therefore E[g(X)] can be simplifies. I can take the integral by part and change the $$d v$$ over which I am integrating. I end up with a final solution of $$ \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} exp(- q) $$ where $$ q= z^2/(2 \sigma^2) $$ Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Forgot that the mean is 0. I'll update the answer to include that.